# How do I simulate browser events when writing tests for React js?

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs

How do I simulate a click on a div element? Or a mouse move? Or text input?

How do I do it in a server side nodejs environment, like mocha?
And how do I do it in a browser environment, with a runner like karma?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since version React 0.9, we've included [ReactTestUtils](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) which is a small bundle of tools to help you test your components. The most useful part of it is event simulation -- you can run `ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(node)` in order to simulate a click event using React's synthetic event system.

There's also a few other useful utilities there for making assertions about the DOM structure. Just download the development addons build (`react-with-addons.js`) and pull it out like so:

```
var ReactTestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(node);
```

Let me know if anything's unclear here.

Comment: The issue you referenced has now been resolved - the way to access `ReactTestUtils` is to use `react-with-addons.js` and call `React.addons.TestUtils`

Answer (score 20):

I have found it generally better to decouple the event handlers from the state change logic, which is the stuff I actually want to test.

For example, I have a component that needs to do something in reaction to the "tab" keypress

```
// this is hooked up in my render function
onKeyPress: function (e) {
  if (e === 9) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.onTab(e.shiftKey)
    return
  }
  ..
},
onTab: function (shift) {
  var newstate = states.tab(shift, this.state)
  if (newstate) this.setState(newstate)
}
```

Then in the `states.js` file I have the logic handling how I should change the state based on the current state and the fact that the user pressed the tab key. **This `states.tab` method is 100% unittestable because it is "pure" — no side-effects**. It takes in a state, and returns the new state.

**And maybe this didn't "answer the question" directly, but I'm trying to be helpful =)** decoupling your state-changing logic from the event handlers will make your code a lot more testable and maintainable.

That's not to say that you never need to simulate events — it can be useful for many cases, including in a smoketest to make sure everything's wired up correctly. **But I have just found that most of the time when I wanted to simulate browser events it was because my code was too coupled.**